# Probabilistic modelling MCMC question with pyMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, pymc

This is my first post and I am a newby in pymc.
I am trying to model a non-linear system (see below for a further explanation). I create my synthetic data with:

```
data = np.random.normal(8., data_std, 1000)
obs = pm.Normal("obs", coupling, value=data, observed=True)
```

My stochastic variable is:

```
phi = pm.Uniform("phi", -180, 180., value=-150)
```

and it is related to the data though the deterministic function:

```
@pm.deterministic
def coupling(phi=phi, a=a,b=b,c=c):
     """
     Calculate the J-coupling  from Karplus forumula
     """
     ang=phi*3.1415/180.
     return a*np.cos(ang)**2+b*np.cos(ang)+c
```

(a,b,c are scalars. In the future, I'll try to see what happens when they are also stochatic variables)

Then my model is:

```
model = pm.Model([obs, phi])
mcmc = pm.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(20000, burn=1000, burn_till_tuned=False)
```

What I don't understand is why the posterior distribution of phi does not depend on the dispersion of the data. That is, I get the same std of `phi_trace` whether data_std is 0.1 or 2. What I am doing wrong?

```
phi_trace = mcmc.trace("phi")[:]
print "\n Phi std:", phi_trace.std()
```

Thanks in advance,
Ramon

PS. I know the nonlinearity of the system may cause the model to get trapped to one of the solutions, say close to -150 and not explore 0 or +150. I'll try to deal with that in the future...

PS2. Some background: phi is a dihedral angle of a molecule and the coupling is what can be measured experimentally. In fact a uniform distribution for phi is a bad prior, but I wanted to see the difference when using more informative priors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question...
The reason is that I am defining the observed data (obs) as a normal distribution, but I am not including the precision of the distribution as a stochastic variable.
The correct model should be:

```
tau = pm.Normal('tau', 5., .05) #or other possible choices...
obs = pm.Normal("obs", coupling, tau, value=data, observed=True)
model = pm.Model([obs, phi, tau])
```

Now the posterior of phi depends on the dispersion of data, as expected...